# Jquery: How do I get the url of an anchor contained within a clicked 'li' tag?

Tags: jquery

The following is a segment of HTML in one of my pages:

```
<li class="prodcat-line">
   <a title="foobar" class="prodcat" href="/some/url.php">Foobar</a>
</li>
```

I want to be able to retrieve the url of the clicked on li tag. My "jQuery fu"  IS NOT WHAT IT SHOULD BE. I know how to bind the click event of li elements of class "prodcat-line", but I don't know how to extract nested tags from within the clicked item - can anyone help?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
$('.prodcat-line').click(function(){
    alert($('a', this).attr('href'));
    return false;
});
```

**Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6ZNda/).**

Comment: exactly what I needed, thanks. I'll accept your answer as soon as I'm able to (in about 7 mins)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/4XU8h/

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
$('.prodcat').click(function(event) {
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
});
```

Since you only have the link within the LI, you don't need to reference the LI. Every click on the LI will target the link anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you select out the `li` like so

```
$(".prodcat-line")....
```

Then, you can either select direct descendents using '>':

```
$(".prodcat-line>a")....
$(".prodcat-line>a.prodcat")....
$(".prodcat-line>.prodcat")....
```

Or, using jQuery `children` method:

```
$(".prodcat-line").children("a")...
$(".prodcat-line").children("a.prodcat")...
$(".prodcat-line").children(".prodcat")...
```

Or from any descendent, omit the `>` and use just a space:

```
$(".prodcat-line a")....
$(".prodcat-line a.prodcat")....
$(".prodcat-line .prodcat")....
```

Or, again, using a jQuery method, this time `find`:

```
$(".prodcat-line").find("a")...
$(".prodcat-line").find("a.prodcat")...
$(".prodcat-line").find(".prodcat")...
```

Answer (score 0):

Whan you click on th li tag you can have his child elements. Two way to do this.

```
$('.prodcat-line').click(function() {
    $(this).children('a').attr('href');
    //or
    $('a', this).attr('href');
});
```